# replacing windows 8.1 with CentOS 7

Tags: centos, boot, windows, usb, bootable

A new computer came pre-installed with Windows 8.1.  It is an Acer Aspire T desktop.  **I would like to completely erase windows 8.1 forever from the machine, and replace it with CentOS 7.  How can I accomplish this?**

So far, I have created a boot stick using pen drive Linux and changed the boot order in the machine to pick the boot stick first.  But this is resulting in a error stating there is a problem loading in-kernel x.509 certificate (-129).  Somehow, **I think that the current error is the result of a wrong approach, so I would really appreciate it if someone could describe the correct approach instead of diagnosing my current error.**

Comment: Are you using LiveDVD or the installation media?

Comment: @JonKittell I am using a USB stick.  I tried two different ones in fact.

Comment: The X509 certificate issue is probably because your computer is configured to use Secure Boot.  Disable that in the boot options (BIOS settings). If that fails, confirm that your computer's date isn't set to a far off date.